# Website 'resizing' after going live? (vs localhost)

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, width

Okay, weird question because I have a weird problem. Have tried to figure out what's happening without luck.

The website is fine in localhost but when it is uploaded on wordpress live the body resizing (even though the max width is set to 1400px its not growing).

Ideas please? [Website Link Here](http://mockup.radian3.com/)

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Comment: Mine works great, I don’t know what happened

Answer (score 1, accepted):

plz change below css style width:60%; to width:100%; -

```
    @media screen and (min-width: 900px){
        .archive-view.has-sidebar .content-area {
        /*  width: 60%; */
        width:100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: in style.css line no. 2220

Comment: but its working in localhost, perfectly. that is the problem

Comment: Is there any style.css file version or theme version change ?

Comment: no i've literally zipped the local host version and uploaded